# c# Port data send trouble

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, send

I am making SW that uses CAD drawing to generate G-code, and then sends it to arduino. So far so good, everything work on arduino (Arduino UNO, I use Arduino IDE), except one thing. In one form, that is used to actually run G-code and show tool possition. When I run the program, C# app sends one line of G-code, Arduino receive it, runs it. It sends number of steps, that it have done, it works and shows ok. After it is done, it sends an `"OK"` message(it does) and after that message code should send another line of G-Code, but it does not. Could anyone help me? thanks

Code in C#: 
Run button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button1.Text = "<RUNNING>";
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        while (!port.IsOpen)
        {

        }
        if (port.IsOpen)
        {
            data_comm();

        }
    }
```

Read port:

```
 public void Read()
    {
        while (port.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                string message = port.ReadLine();
                if (message == "OK")
                {
                    data_comm();
                }
                else
                {
                    SetText(message);
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }
```

Send data(G-Code):

```
public void data_comm()
    {

        textBox3.Text = SortedList;
        string[] word = SortedList.Split(' ');
        if (word[0] == "G1")
        {
            string x = Math.Round(double.Parse(word[1].Remove(0, 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / precission_X_Y, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
            string y = Math.Round(double.Parse(word[2].Remove(0, 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / precission_X_Y, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
            port.WriteLine("#G01X" + x + "Y" + y);
        }
        else if (word[0] == "G0")
        {
            string x = Math.Round(double.Parse(word[1].Remove(0, 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / precission_X_Y, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
            string y = Math.Round(double.Parse(word[2].Remove(0, 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / precission_X_Y, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
            port.WriteLine("#G00X" + x + "Y" + y);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Read position from Arduino:

```
private void SetText(string text)
    {
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.TranslateTransform(0, pictureBox1.Height);
        g.ScaleTransform(0.3f, -0.3f);


        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired && this.textBox2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });

        }
        else
        {

            try
            {
                x_pos = Single.Parse(text.Substring(1, 6)) * 0.07f;
                y_pos = Single.Parse(text.Substring(8, 6)) * 0.07f;
                this.textBox1.Text = Math.Round(x_pos, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString();
                this.textBox2.Text = Math.Round(y_pos, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString();
                g.DrawRectangle(p, x_pos, y_pos, 1, 1);
                string[] word = SortedList[i].Split(' ');

            }
            catch { }           

        }
    }
```

[`message`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmewx.png)

Comment: I am assuming your data_comm() works, so it looks like your IF "OK" does not trigger. Debug by printing the message-variable, I am guessing it has some white spaces or other characters so it does not evaluate correctly. Just check if the message string CONTAINS "OK" and see if it triggers?

Comment: I checked, and i have forgot to write it. message is OK, but it is not triggered

Comment: Try .contains to trigger after "OK".

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much :)